# Using JMX / JMS to broadcast a message to all sessions of a web app?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jms, jmx

I have a Spring MVC web app running on my server. Recently I wanted to add a functionality to notify any logged in users that their role has changed, so they can logout and in again.

I thought about using JMX, so did a small test and it worked fine, except that its not broadcasting the message. So for example, if i have 2 logged in persons, only 1 is receiving the message.

So my question is, is it possible to broadcast a message with JMX to all instances of a web app (active sessions)?

Edit - using JMS

So I am trying with JMS right now, here is my configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="connectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
</bean>
<bean id="msgDestination"
      class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="userToLogout.topic"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userNotifier"
      class="com.cap.messaging.UserNotifier">
    <property name="destination" ref="msgDestination"/>
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userNotificationListener"
      class="com.cap.messaging.UserNotificationListener">
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="userToLogout.topic" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="userNotificationListener" />
</bean>
```

This isnt working right now. However it works if I change the ActiveMQTopic to ActiveMQQueue. what am I missing here, and would this work?

Comment: If someone is interested in the solution, I just added an Application scoped bean, and simulated a publish-subscribe communication. kinda did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is no.  [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html) is a single connection API which uses [RMI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/rmi/RMI.html) over TCP/IP sockets. Best you can do is to serially unicast to all of your instances or use threads and send to all of your web app sessions in parallel over a number of JMX client connections.

Comment: So would it be possible with JMS then? with JMS i can create topics. I am trying that atm, but creating a topic seems to not work for now..

Comment: Sure you could use JMS and have all of your servers subscribe.  There are many different remoting packages that could be used.  You'll need to ask another question however about the details there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I edited my question, basically what I am interested in is the notification aspect. I already thought of a reasonable alternative, such as an application wide bean which holds the user list that should be logged out, but I am leaving it as a last resort.